What is the best way to add a Quine to my resume?
My resume is currently written in latex, but that isn't essential. I had the idea a while ago of adding a QR code to my resume which when scanned would generate the exact latex code for the entire resume, including the part for the QR code itself.
As it stands my resume, without having lines dedicated to creating a QR code, is about 12,000 characters long. This can and would need to be significantly reduced.
I am not committed to keeping the format in Latex either.
The obvious issue is the size restriction of a QR code, and similar technologies. The max size for a QR code is just under 3KB, and even competitors meant to store more information such as a data matrix max out at just over 1.5KB.
Even if I were to shorten the code for my resume, the overhead for the quine would make it impossible to fit in 3KB. Atleast, i think it would.
What I am asking for here is for any ideas that could make this possible, or even feasible to attempt. Alternative data stores to QR codes that could be much much larger (while also having relatively common packages to generate them). I am also open to alternatives to latex if that could potentially make things a lot easier, although I do not think that is a major limiting feature.
Or any quine building advice that would help with this. The QR code does not need to return latex code either. it could return for example python code which when run returns the original latex code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

why not simply attach the tex file to the pdf?

That is pretty reasonable, but that would make it a 2 page resume. Certainly that is the easiest way of doing it, and tbh I did not even consider that. The QR code does give the benefit that you can scan it if you have a physical copy rather than a pdf, but obviously that is an outdated use case
